# Power of a constant entity

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I was trying to solve this problem:

> A driver notices that her 1150-kg car slows down from 85 Km/h to 65 Km/h in about 6.0 s on the level when it is in neutral. Approximately what power (watts and hp) is needed to keep the car traveling at a constant
>   75 km/h?

1) So first I thought that since we needed to keep the car going at a constant velocity ($75$km/h) then that would mean that the net kinetic energy would be $0$,so the work for be $0$, so then w/t = 0/t, then power would equal to $0$. However, $0$ watts of power was not the correct answer.

2) I solved for the power the car used to decelerate:

$$P = \frac{\frac{1}{2}m(V_f^2 - V_i^2)}{t}$$

$$P = \frac{\frac{1}{2}(1150)(18.1^2 - 23.6^2)}{6}$$

$$P = 2.2 \times 10^6W$$

So I found the power for when the car decelerated, but I don't know how to connect that with finding the power to keep the car going at a constant velocity. What confuses me even more is that the answer is the power for the car decelerating ($2.2 \times 10^6W$). Why is this the answer?

Comment: That "deceleration" of the car was caused purely by friction as soon as they turned the engine off (neutral).  This implies you have to overcome that friction to maintain constant velocity.  I think that might be where you were confused.

Comment: @JMacThen wouldn't this friction cause it to decelerate to 0m/s?

Comment: it would if we were looking at it for more than 6 seconds.  We are only considering what happens after 6 seconds, not until it stops.

Comment: @JMac I calculated the power of friction to transform kinetic energy into heat right? so why is that the answer, when I don't even incorporate the 75km/h?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power $=$ frictional force $\times$ velocity.
Assume the frictional force is constant.

You can find the frictional force from the information given by first evaluating the acceleration of the car.

Comment: How can you find the frictional force? I evaluated the acceleration of the car, which would be (65-85)/6

Comment: @pablo Which force is slowing down the car with this acceleration? Make sure you use a correct set of units.